# SQL server 2008 Log shipping Failback

Tags: log-shipping

I need to set up log shipping for about 10 databases. The primary server is accessed by our website and the secondary server is a BI server. What I am struggling to figure out at moment is the best way to handle a “failback” situation once a failover has occurred. How do I get the primary server back to being the main server for the website?

Does anyone have any suggestions or best practices to handle a failback?

We are using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended solution is to not failback instead switch roles as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178117.aspx). I think they even recommend that the failover server should be named something like Prod2 instead of JustincasefailoverServer

But you could switch two times and your set where you want to be. Rationalize it by that you want to make sure that the server who failed should prove that it is capable of being up and running for a day or two.